# C# Does not encrypt all lines in a file

Tags: c#, encryption

I am working on a "Kill Switch" program in C# where if I do not verify in the software within a time limit it will encrypt all of my files using B64(I will make my own algorithm later on) but currently there is a error where the software does not encrypt all lines of code, it only encrypts the first line and then deletes the rest. Any ideas?

Code:

```
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles("D:/Desktop/encTest"))
{
    string msg = "";

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        msg = Base64StringEncode(sr.ReadLine());
    }

    string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(docPath, fileName)))
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

I also have a function for B64 encryption!

Comment: Well yeah, you're only calling `ReadLine()` once for each file. Why not use `File.ReadAllText()`?

Comment: Also, base 64 encoding is NOT encryption.

Comment: Duplicate linked above is specifically adressing large file sizes, but I think you'll find that using CryptoStream + ToBase64Transform makes it easier to refactor to use an actual encryption algorithm in the future

Comment: in addition to gunr's comment: ***DO NOT EVER*** make your own encryption algorithm unless you know ***exactly*** what you are doing, and have a degree to prove it. _thank you_. also: seems more like potential malware.

Comment: Franz Gleichmann It is not malware. I am making my own personal project for fun and I will not distribute any of it

Comment: @Beemo that's why i used the word "potential".

Comment: Before you study encryption, you need to study [how to debug](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Answer (score -1):

You do not have a loop anywhere. It sets msg variable to the encrypted equivalent of your first line in the input file.

You need to implement a loop for that if you want to do it line by line.